# CakePHP question: is there any problem with 755 permission on server?

Tags: php, permissions

My website on server is with 755 permission for all files .

Is there any problem with this permission ? Is this permission vulnearable ? Or should i decrease the permission ?

How can i stop seeing javascript and css files of that website ? Is that possible ?

From page view source one can easily see javascript and css files and can download it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

644 is probably better than 755 because website resource files are usually not directly executable.

Aside from that, you cannot (well, should not) stop someone from seeing Javascript and CSS files. A user's browser needs to be able to download those files in order to render the website correctly.

Answer (score 3):

1.For files, you don't need to execute them, so 644 is better than 755.

2.You can't stop others seeing or downloading your javascript and css, they are living in the client.

Comment: Here, files are not include the directories.

Comment: That wasn't my point :) I wanted you to differentiate between php files and assets such as images, js and css.

Comment: What's the problem with 755 permission. From cpanel if i change the permission to 644 i can't browse the website. I got Can't access app/webroot/ etc..

Comment: @chelmertz So how do you want differentiate them? It's ok for both of them to have 644.

Comment: @guru Sorry, the directory should be 755, what I mean is the php files and other web resource files.